# schedule a python script to run every hour

Tags: python, timer, windows-10, scheduler

I am trying to write a script that executes every hour
but, when I run it... it takes an hour to run the job for the first time and then, it starts running like every 5 seconds
I don't understand what am I doing wrong here

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job():
    print('excuting job')


scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, 'interval', hours = 1)
scheduler.start()
```

this is another code that I have used, but it's the same result

```
schedule.every().hour.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Have you considered using the builtin task scheduler with your operating system?

Comment: the built-in task scheduler only provides daily, monthly or weekly task triggers.

Comment: What OS are you on? I have a task that runs every 15 minutes on Windows

Comment: I am on windows 10, I have just opened the task scheduler and i tried to create basic task ... I see only daily, weekly and monthly

Comment: [Windows](https://techrando.com/2019/06/22/how-to-execute-a-task-hourly-in-task-scheduler/)/[Linux](https://net2.com/task-scheduling-on-linux-crontab/)

Comment: Could it be that your job is failing and that the scheduler tries to run it again?

Comment: In the apscheduler example [example](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/interval.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.interval) they have ```from datetime import datetime``` and mention that start_date by default is ```datetime.now() + interval ```. Might try adding the ```datetime``` import.

Comment: @Roy2012 .. no, the job is being executed perfectly

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I know .. the start_date by default is datetime.now() + interval, which is working correctly because my script takes an hour to execute the first job..... the problem is; after the first execution it starts executing like every five seconds.

Comment: So try the import and see if it helps. What happens if you use  a different interval say  ```minutes = 5```?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it in python.
Make a file called exehour.bat with this (assuming you're using Windows):

```
@echo off
cd DIRECTORY-OF-FILE
:loop
timeout 3600
FILE-NAME
goto loop
```

So this will execute a file every 1 hour when you run it
Or if you need it in python

```
import time
def runhour():
   #YOUR PYTHON CODE GOES UNDERNEATH HERE


   #
   time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: Though this is a potential solution the ops question it's best to provide context and attempt at solving the solution within the ops scope.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do within your def, like a rogue brake or other bad while loop or sleep timer. Maybe the checking job timer not being short enough is affecting something as well?

```
import schedule # I'm not sure about the BlockingScheduler import but this one works for me
import time     # Hate how we need an import for this and it's not built into python....

def job():
    print('executing job')

# Run your job on first boot without the scheduler
job()

# Then setup the schedule to be used from now on
schedule.every().hour.do(job)

# Check every second if we can do our job yet or not
# Bonus heartbeat . so you know the while loop is running and not crashed.
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1) # seconds
```

If it runs our job() then gets stuck, boot loops or crashes then its in your job def.
if it runs fine the first time, sets up the schedule fine but then gets stuck with executing the schedule then I don't really have any ideas without seeing more of the job() def..
for shits and giggles you could pip uninstall and reinstall schedule again and see if that helps idk..